# How to pass instance of class to dataTransfer.setData?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have instance of class:

```
let element = new Element();
```

Then I tried to serialize this and add to dataTransfer (drag and drop):

```
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("data", JSON.stringify(element));
```

Somewhere I need to get this object `data` and deserialize to object.

I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Because class `Element` contains some initilized classed inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-safe package to get your circular js object converted to string.

Or if you can change setData second parameter to accept object reference using `any` type then remove JSON.stringify and pass element directly to setData where JS use call by reference for non primitive data types

Comment: But `dataTransfer.setData` supports only string data as second parameter

Comment: So you can use this package to stringify your object https://github.com/moll/json-stringify-safe

Comment: Could you explain more about `Or if you can change setData second parameter`

Comment: Seems it works without jsonEncoding:     ev.dataTransfer.setData("data", element);